# Stability on sphere: Only negative eigenvalues whose eigenspaces are tangent to the sphere are relevant?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

If for $\vec{x}=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\in S^{n-1}$ I have a linear ODE system $$\frac{d}{dt}\vec{x}=A\vec{x}$$ with $A$, say, diagonalizable (i.e. with $n$ simple eigenvalues) and an equilibrium $\vec{x}_0$ which is a saddle  then in full dimension $n$ this equilibrium is unstable. But since everything lives on the sphere, stability then just means that I need those negative eigenvalues whose eigenspaces are tangent to the sphere at $\vec{x}_0$, right? There are, so to speak, too much dimensions and some can be neglected for the dynamics on the sphere. So I would say that the equilibrium can still be considered stable on the sphere under the condition that the unstable eigenvalues have eigenspaces which are not tangent to the sphere at $\vec{x}_0$ and there is at least one negative eigenvalue whose eigenspace is tangent to the sphere at $\vec{x}_0$. Is that correct?

Or to put it otherwise: The ODEs are only describing the flow tangentially to the sphere. Hence all transverse eigendirections can be neglected and are meaningless on the sphere.

If this is correct understanding:

1. How can I find, say, the largest negative eigenvalue whose eigenspace is tangent to the sphere at $\vec{x}_0$? And how can I show whether the eigenspace corresponding to another eigenvalue is transverse?
2. Am I right that the negative eigenvalues whose eigenspaces are not tangent to the sphere at $\vec{x}_0$ can be also neglected because they are irrelevant for the dynamics on the sphere?
3. To sum it up: How can I select those eigenvalues whose eigenspaces are tangent to  the sphere at the equilibrium considered? And if I have selected these, how can I next find the negative eigenvalues of this type?

To be more concrete:

Lets say, $n=3$, and the eigenvalues are $\lambda_1=-1, \lambda_2=-4$ and $\lambda_3=7$. Then in dimension $n$ only $\lambda_{1,2}$ are stable eigenvalues. How can I know whether the corresponding eigenspaces are tangent to $\vec{x}_0$ and thus are relevant for the dynamics on the sphere? Is it possible that none/ both/ exactly only one of them is?

In full dimension $n$, the largest negative eigenvalue should be dominant, here $\lambda_2$. But can it be that its eigenspace is not tangent but that of $\lambda_1$ is so that only $\lambda_1$ is relevant for stability on the sphere?

*Much text, but I hope you got my problem.*

---

Maybe I can illustrate my problem with a concrete easy example.

Let $\vec{x}=(x_1,x_2)\in S^1=\{\vec{y}\in\mathbb{R}^2: \lVert\vec{y}\rVert=1\}$ and consider the ODE system
$$
\begin{align*}
x_1'&=x_1(-x_1+x_1^3+x_2^3-x_1x_2^2)\\
x_2'&=x_2(x_1-x_2+x_1^3+x_2^3-x_1x_2^2).
\end{align*}
$$
Consider the equilibrium $\vec{e}=\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{5}},2\sqrt{\frac{1}{5}}\right)$. The linearization in this equilibrium gives
$$
\vec{x}'=\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{6}{5}\sqrt{\frac{1}{5}} & \frac{8}{5}\sqrt{\frac{1}{5}}\\\frac{8}{5}\sqrt{\frac{1}{5}}&\frac{6}{5}\sqrt{\frac{1}{5}}\end{pmatrix}(\vec{x}-\vec{e})
$$
This matrix has eigenvalue $\lambda_1=2\sqrt{\frac{1}{5}}$ and $\lambda_2=-2\sqrt{\frac{1}{5}}$. So in dimension $n=2$ it is a saddle point and thus unstable. But is this equilibrium stable on $S^1$?

One eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda_1$ is $\vec{v}_1=\begin{pmatrix}1\\\frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}$.

One eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda_2$ is $\vec{v}_2=\begin{pmatrix}1\\-\frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}$.

It looks a bit as if the unstable direction (spanned by $\vec{v}_1$) is transverse to $S^1$ in $\vec{e}$, while the stable direction is tangent to $S^1$ in $\vec{e}$.

Indeed for the scalar products, $\langle\vec{e},\vec{v}_2\rangle=0$ while $\langle\vec{e},\vec{v}_1\rangle\neq 0$.

Doesn't that mean that for the question of stability on the sphere $S^1$, only the Eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda_2$ (the stable one) is relevant for the dynamics on $S^1$ so that $\vec{e}$ is locally stable on $S^1$?

Comment: $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\vec x=A\vec x$ will in general take $\vec x$ off the sphere; so you need to say something on how you mean this, how you intend to maintain the constraint.

Comment: @joriki For example by saying that there is additional dynamics transverse to the sphere which puts everything back to the sphere? Say, $x(t)=r(t)\varphi(t)$ (polar coordinates) and $r'(t)<0$?

Comment: Then how are we to assess the stability if we don't know these additional dynamics?

Comment: Say, we assume that these transverse dynamics are known to be stable.

Comment: I think that everything is ill-posed UNLESS $A$ is skew-symmetric. In that case, $x(t)$ stays on the sphere.

Comment: OK, I looked at the example; unfortunately I still don't get it. And your last comment makes the question even more mysterious to me. If you constrain $\vec x$ to the sphere, then there is *only* transverse dynamics. If you *assume* that they're stable, then what is the question about?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion... I thought that when we restrict to the sphere, then only the *tangent* dynamics are relevant and the transverse are not.

Comment: OK, then I didn't understand how you were using those terms. I see. So are you essentially saying that $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}x$ is the orthogonal projection of $A\vec x$ onto the tangent plane?

Comment: I do not know if I am saying this. I think this is why I am confused. We have dimension $n$ and in this dimension, the equilibrium, when being a saddle, is unstable. However, if we restrict to the sphere, then the ODE just describes the *tangent* flow on the sphere, doesn't it? And s my naive thought was that only the *tangent* dynamics are relevant, say, for stability. Now, if I look at the example, it is a saddle in dimension $n=2$, but the stable direction is tangent (I think), while the unstable is transverse (I think). So isn't the equilibrium stable when restricting to the sphere?

Comment: But you are right: How are we ensured that we stay on the sphere? And thus, my thought was that one might assume that there is some additional (say stable) dynamics which pushes everything back to the sphere when we leave the sphere. Say, some dynamics in the radius, $r'(t)<0$.

Comment: The "doesn't it?" is where I don't understand how you're approaching this. You seem to think that "restrict to the sphere" is a well-defined process that you can ask us about. It's not; you have to specify how the dynamics are restricted to the sphere; otherwise there's no well-defined problem to talk about. One way to do that is to say that $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}x$ is the orthogonal projection of $A\vec x$ to the tangent plane. If that's not what you want, then you need to say something else that defines what you mean by "restrict to the sphere".

Comment: "Dynamics that pushes everything back to the sphere" seems like just an unnecessarily complicated way of saying that you want to ignore (i.e. project out) the component of $A\vec x$ normal to the sphere; if so, that's exactly what it means to say that $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}x$ is the orthogonal projection of $A\vec x$ to the tangent plane.

Comment: Ok, I see your point. Then my next question would be: If we project the "full dynamics" in dimension $n$ onto the sphere and the equilibrium is a saddle. How can we answer the question whether it is stable on the sphere? Which eigenvalues are relevant which are not? How are the eigenspaces projected and which are relevant?

Comment: OK, next question: Shouldn't it be $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}(\vec x-\vec e)=A(\vec x-\vec e)$ if you linearize at the equilibrium $\vec e$?

Comment: Indeed, the linearized system in $\vec{e}$ is $\vec{x}'=A\cdot (\vec{x}-\vec{e})$ where $A$ is the Jacobian evaluated in $\vec{e}$.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. The equations on the manifold $S^1$ only have a meaning tangentially to $S^1$. So instead of projecting away the normal direction, can't we just ignore those dynamics which are not tangent? In my example, if I computed correctly, the stable Eigenspace is tangent to $S^1$ at $\vec{e}$ while the unstable Eigenspace isn't. So, if we put only tangent dynamics into consideration, only the stable Eigenspace is relevant. While when we project orthogonally, as you suggested. also the unstable Eigenspace is relevant since it is not normal.

Comment: "Once the tangent spaces of a manifold have been introduced, one can define vector fields, which are abstractions of the velocity field of particles moving in space. A vector field attaches to every point of the manifold a vector from the tangent space at that point, in a smooth manner. Such a vector field serves to define a generalized ordinary differential equation on a manifold: A solution to such a differential equation is a differentiable curve on the manifold whose derivative at any point is equal to the tangent vector attached to that point by the vector field." (Wikipedia)

Comment: Doesn't this quote from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space also suggest that only the tangent dynamics are relevant and the others can be ignored (without projecting)?

Comment: I don't understand the third comment above (before the Wikipedia quote). The matrix is symmetric, so it should have orthogonal eigenspaces. If one of the eigenspaces is tangent to the sphere, then the other must be normal to it, no? (I don't get notified unless you ping me; I just read this because I happened to look at the page again.)

Comment: @joriki Thank you. That was exactly the explanation which I was missing, Because I was wondering what happens with the eigenspaces which are not tangent: Now I see that they are normal automatically and thus are irrelevant when doing the orthogonal projection.

Comment: Great. If this has answered your question, you might want to write up a short summary as an answer and accept it so that the question doesn't remain unanswered.

Comment: I will. Thanks again and have a nice day :)